# How to make PHP html table have color mismatch between rows?

Tags: php, html, colors, html-table, rows

I am learning PHP as I code. From an example on w3schools it showed using PHP and msql to display database results on a html table. My questions is, I now have too many rows and I could not make them have mismatch colors between rows. I've tried adding style span and font color after `<td` but it doesn't take it. the entire PHP just don't work if I do so.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","peter","abc123");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Persons");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

The output of the code above will be:

```
Firstname   Lastname
Glenn   Quagmire
Peter   Griffin
```

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Comment: So, you want alternating colors in the output table?

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you mean by color mismatch. Assuming that you mean *alternating row colors* I'd do the following:

```
$odd = false;

while (...)
{
    echo '<tr class="'.($odd ? "odd" : "even").'">';
    ...
    echo "</tr>";
    $odd = !$odd;
}
```

Now you have the `tr` element being of class `odd` or `even` alternatingly, and may specify some additional background color for one of them in your CSS, e.g.:

```
tr.odd { background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05); }
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
```

with this:

```
$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr ". ($i % 2 == 0 ? 'style="background-color:grey;"' : '' .">";
  echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  $i++;
  }
```

Every other row will have grey color.

Answer (score 1):

```
$class = "even";    
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  if($class == "even")
  {
    echo "<tr class='$class'>";
    $class = "odd";
  }
  else
  {
    echo "<tr class='$class'>";
    $class = "even";
  }

  echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

CSS

```
tr.even
{
    background-color:blue;//Pick your own color
}

tr.odd
{
    background-color:green;
}
```

Here is a list of [color names](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_colornames.asp). If you want a more detailed color choices, click [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_colormixer.asp?colorbottom=000000&colortop=FFFFFF).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use this approach with jquery

```
<script src="text/javascript">
    $('#table tbody tr:odd').addClass('odd');
    $('#table tbody tr:even').addClass('even');
</script>
```

and then add the styles

```
.odd { background-color: #color }
.even { background-color: #color }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
  $flag = 0;
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  if ($flag%2 == 1)
  echo "<tr bgcolor=#123345>";
  else
  echo echo "<tr bgcolor=#643235>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  $flag = $flag +1;
  }
```

Comment: sorry. I was just trying to help. I thought it was apparent that I meant replace. Did not mean to confuse anyone.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it's really clear for me to understand the work around.